# Find the Polynomial Function for a Sequence

Tags: polynomials

Find polynomial $f(n)$ such that for all integers $n \geq 1,$ we have

$$3\left( 1\cdot2 + 2\cdot3 + \ldots + n(n+1) \right) = f(n).$$

Write $f(n)$ as a polynomial with terms in descending order of $n.$

I tried rewriting it, but with no success.

Comment: "in descending order of $n$": what does that mean ??

Comment: It means that the largest power of $n$ goes first, then the second-largest, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creative telescoping:
$$3\left( 1\cdot2 + 2\cdot3 + \ldots + n(n+1) \right)=3\sum_{k=1}^nk(k+1)\\=\sum_{k=1}^n(3k^2+3k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[(k+1)^3-k^3-1\right]\\=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[(k+1)^3-k^3\right]-n=
(n+1)^3-1-n\\=n^3+3n^2+2n.$$

Comment: Nice use of that factor of 3.

Comment: Efficient and neat, thanks for answering, Robert Z!

Answer (score 2):

$f(n+1)-f(n)=n(n+1)$ which is a quadratic polynomial. Then $f$ must be a cubic polynomial (so that the leading terms cancel out).

Knowing that it's a cubic polynomial, you determine it by Lagrangian interpolation on four points: $$0\to0,\\1\to6,\\2\to24,\\3\to60.$$

This yields

$$n^3+3n^2+2n.$$

---

You make it slightly shorter by noting that there is no independent term and the polynomial $P(n)/n$ follows

$$1\to6,\\2\to12,\\3\to20.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Show that $f$ must be a cubic (that is, of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$). To do this, think about the *growth rate* of $f$. Can you think of two cubics you can easily write down which $f$ must always lie between? *SUBHINT: Think about the closed-form [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) for the sum of the first $k$ squares.* Do you see why that means $f$ must be cubic itself?

Then you can use interpolation: knowing four different values of a cubic, you know the entire cubit (this is a generalization of the fact that two points determine a line: in general, $k+1$ points determines a degree-$k$ polynomial).

Comment: Thanks for your hints, Noah Schweber!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible hints:

1. Observe the trend for a few small $n$'s, and then prove by induction.
2. Telescoping.
3. Write $3k(k+1)$ as $a\binom{k}{2}+b\binom{k}{1}+c\binom{k}{0}$ for some constants $a,b,c$.  There is a general theorem stating that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\,\sum_{j=0}^r\,a_j\,\binom{k}{j}=\sum_{j=0}^r\,a_j\,\binom{n+1}{j+1}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering, Batominovski!